# Is there a way of visualizing a Drake SceneGraph in ROS RViz?

Tags: python, c++, scenegraph, drake

I am working on a project that uses a `MultiBodyPlant` and a `SceneGraph` in `Drake`. Is there a way of visualizing the links and joints of the plant in `ROS RViz`?

Answer (score 2):

Currently (as of 2020/05/11, [drake@3cae4801](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/commit/3cae4801eac3f9cc3d948c193022ebb8bfba5124)), Rviz is not officially supported.

However, I have made a (hacky) example for ROS1 Rviz (Melodic, Python 2) using `pydrake` (Python 3) which you can see here:

[`EricCousineau-TRI/repro/ros/drake_ros1_hacks`](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/master/ros/drake_ros1_hacks) ([permalink](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/tree/39f79009a2e89b987f072276d1921a282f63e6a1/ros/drake_ros1_hacks))

Please see the `README` for what the current issues are, how to try it out, etc. Here's a snippet:

> [image: README snippet]